# HTML E-Mail / C# - Issue

Tags: c#, html

I have following as my HTML body msg (stg)

```
stg= "<br>Thank You,<br><img src=\"D:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Image.png\"><br>Why can't I get this to work?";
```

I get red X for the image.

the image.png exists in the directory.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Your image is a local image, the image URL needs to be accessible from the web.

Comment: +0: same as BossRoss - most e-mail readers will not show the image.

Comment: OHk, that makes sense now (newbie here). Is there a way (tutorial...) to display a local image in the e-mail?

Comment: Alexei, thanks for that info. Do you know if Outlook would have any issue?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov why would most e-mail readers not show the image? Yes they would if SPF records/white listing had been done. The SMTP server sending mails was not blacklisted. If there is no content visible or hidden to the recipient that might constitute as spam/phishing content.

Comment: @BossRoss, Simple fact that you GET image from server indicates the fact that person opened email. I believe web mail generally don't care and show remote content in messages, Outlook by default does not load remote resources. My statement should have been "there are mail clients that will not load remote resource in particular configurations", sorry for overly broad generalization.

Comment: Ah yes that does tend to make more sense. Thank you for the clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You need to point to a URL for the image

```
<img src="www.yourwebsite.com/images/image.png" >
```

Comment: You need to use an absolute URL.

Comment: +0 = +1 for suggestion to use accessible image, -1 as it actually not going to look nice in most e-mail readers due to [beacon issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug). One should embed image into a post.

Comment: Thanks for an example. Is there a way to somehow show a local image in an e-mail?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov "as it actually not going to look nice in most e-mail readers" care to expand? It will look the same if the image is embedded or if it is referenced. Beacon issue is a different story and  its relevance is circumstantial depending on the real world scenario